# How can I create a non-bipartite graph in a bi-partite layout

Tags: python, graph, networkx

I have a graph with lots of nodes. I am going to segregate them based on their timesteps. Let's say I have 3 timesteps and I have 5 nodes for each time step. So I want to create a 3-columned graph where each column has 5 nodes. So if we imagine, it needs to like a bipartite layout. 
But this is not a bipartite graph and hence I am not sure how to proceed

```
# Greate your Bipartite graph object
G = nx.Graph()


y_out = [6, 6, 12 ,8, 23, 23]
# Add nodes to set 0 and 1
G.add_nodes_from(y_out, bipartite=0)
G.add_nodes_from(['a6', 'b6', 'c12', 'd8', 'd23', 'e23'], bipartite=1)

# # Add edges between exclusive sets
# G.add_edges_from([dets_tuple])

top_nodes = {n for n, d in G.nodes(data=True) if d['bipartite'] == 0}
bottom_nodes = set(G) - top_nodes

print("top:", top_nodes)
print("bottom: " ,bottom_nodes)

# Visualize the graph
plt.subplot(121)
nx.draw_networkx(
    G, pos=nx.drawing.layout.bipartite_layout(G, top_nodes))
plt.show()
```

UPDATED CODE:

```
unique_frames = set(y_out[:, 0])
print("Generate dynamic graph")

# Visualize the graph
plt.subplot(121)

for i in unique_frames:

    # find indices that belong to the same frame
    idx = np.where(y_out[:, 0] == i)
    print("Comparing frame no: ", i)
    print("Idx : ", idx)
    # embed()

    curr_nodes = np.asarray(idx)[0]

    # Add nodes to set 0 and 1
    G.add_nodes_from(curr_nodes, bipartite=i)

    # compute partition nodes
    top_nodes = {n for n, d in G.nodes(data=True) if d['bipartite'] == i}

    # Draw Graph
    nx.draw_networkx(G, pos=nx.drawing.layout.bipartite_layout(G, top_nodes))

    plt.show(block=False)
    plt.pause(0.5)
```

This literally shows me a bipartite graph. I have plugged in the nodes temporarily so that it respects the bipartite rule. But ideally I can not have one. How can I construct a normal multiple connected graph with a bipartite layout

Update: The new updated code is creating graphs, but on the same column. I not sure how to space them horizontally

Comment: "So if we imagine, it needs to like a bipartite layout." Why

Comment: @Acccumulation It is more like my requirement. Sorry for miscommunicating

Comment: by "it needs to like a bipartite layout" do you just mean you want the nodes separated based on timestep?  Are there any links between nodes within a tilmestep?

Comment: With this type of question, it usually helps to post a little sketch -- hand-drawn or ascii art tends to work well and is quickly done.